# How can I query the PCI MaxPayloadSize that was negotiated at boot?

Tags: pci

I'm debugging something of an esoteric driver/BIOS compatibility issue. One possible lead I've found is mentions of possible mismatches of / misdetection of PCI Max Payload Size (MPS). I tried rebooting with `pci=pcie_bus_peer2peer` on the kernel command line to limit the MPS to 128 bytes on all nodes, but that didn't solve my problem so I'd like to query to make sure it took effect (and to see if anything changes when I remove it again).

What tools could I use, or where in `/sys` or `/proc` would I look to find the MPS for each of the PCI devices in the tree to my problem device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo lspci -vv |grep -P '^\d|Payload'`

Comment: I see the Max Payload listed under both the `DevCap` and `DevCtl` headings. Should I interpret that as the maximum supported vs. the maximum negotiated?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right.  DevCtl is the live setting.  Some details here: https://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-2496#jive_content_id_PCIe_Max_Payload_Size